# Cannondale Mountainbike Giveaway - Winner Announced

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, contest

The giveaway is on!

**The Prize:**

A [**Cannondale Trail SL 29er 3**](http://www.rei.com/product/827819/cannondale-trail-sl-29er-3-bike-2012) - *or a bicycle of equal or lesser value purchased through [REI](http://www.rei.com/category/4500003_Bicycles)*

[image: Cannondale Trail SL 29er 3]

**The Rules:**

- [Ask a question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) or [leave](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/6940/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-a-cycling-desk) [an](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/6983/what-road-double-cranksets-will-work-with-a-108mm-jis-square-taper-bottom-bracke) [answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/6922/whats-a-good-all-purpose-city-commuting-winter-tire) anywhere at [**Bicycles.StackExchange**](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/) that earns a score of +2 to enter into the contest -- Broadcast your bike wisdom and cycling curiosity to the world!
- Earn [**sharing badges**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/) to multiply your chance of winning

  - **x3** for Announcer Badge (25 unique IPs in 3 days)
  - **x10** for Booster Badge (300 unique IPs in 4 days)
  - **x20** for Publicist Badge (1,000 unique IPs in 5 days)
  - **Note:** Sharing badges can be earned on any question ever asked at Bicycles.StackExchange ([some might be more "shareable"](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes) than others). But be sure to use the sharing icons (Facebook, Twitter) located under the voting arrows, or share the URL in the "Link" button -- these options include your user ID in the URL, which enables us to track your shares.
- This contest will last 2 weeks (Nov 21 - Dec 5), but inbound referrals will be counted through the third week.
- Badges must be earned between Nov 21 and December 11 (start/end dates included) for the multiplyer to take effect.
- A winner will be determined by random drawing and announced **Monday, December 12**.
- **Anyone, anywhere can enter this contest.** However, the prize must be picked up by the contest winner or a friend from an [REI store](http://www.rei.com/stores/storeloc.html) (US only) before Feb. 1, 2012.

**GOOD LUCK!**

Comment: Well that's an improvement. Sadly It won't be possible for me to pick up a bike from the US.

Comment: @Ambo100 - Have a friend in the US who deserves a holiday gift?

Comment: To clarify -- Any answer counts, not just an answer to one of the three linked questions.  Is that right?

Comment: @MatthewRead - yes, answer anywhere to enter!

Comment: Is there a date cutoff for posts/badges? I.e. does your post/badge have to have a date later than the start of the contest?

Comment: @JasonPlank - The badge must be earned between Nov 21 and December 11 (start/end dates included) for the multiplyer to take effect.

Comment: @Sam Same for posts?

Comment: @JasonPlank The cutoff for posts is Dec 5th as I read this.

Answer (score 5):

We have a winner!

[KentB](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/1937/kentb) of Michigan will be taking home a new bike from REI.

KentB earned a +3 for the question ["mountain bike vs. cyclocross bike"](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/7154/mountain-bike-vs-cyclocross-bike).

He is one of 69 users to earn at least a +2 on a question or answer during the contest period. Only one user ([phwd](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/1541/phwd)) earned a sharing badge during the contest period. (Sharing badges and the way they work will be getting a revamp early next year. Stay tuned for details.)

Thanks for participating! The next giveaway is just around the corner.

Comment: Congratulations, @KentB!

Answer (score 3):

FYI, in that price range from REI, there's also these bikes you could win instead:

- A Good [Cyclocross-inspired Commuter](http://www.rei.com/product/825675/marin-lombard-bike-2012) from Marin (if I win this is what I'd probably get) [image: Marin Lombard Bike 2012]
- A [Cannondale Road Bike](http://www.rei.com/product/827845/cannondale-synapse-7-bike-2012) (aluminum frame, carbon fork) [image: Cannondale Synapse 7 2012]
- A [well-equipped traditional commuter](http://www.rei.com/product/808783/novara-fusion-bike-2012) [image: Novara Fusion Bike]

Comment: The Marin and the Cannondale are both nice, and even though I'm in Canada, it's not too far to an REI, so hopefully I'll get a couple votes on my question!

Answer (score 3):

While I absolutely think this contest is a great idea for promoting bicycles.se, it is sad to see that limited to US residents , especially as US users only make up [approx 50% of the user base](http://data.stackexchange.com/bicycles/s/1650/which-country-are-the-users-from).

Yes, as @SamTheBrand pointed out, if you know someone in the US who deserves a new bike you could give it to them.  However, that is not exactly as much fun as winning a bike for yourself. Alturistic? Yes.  Fun? No.
<sub>Please don't get hung up on the pros/cons of gift giving, I'm just trying to make a not-too-serious point ; )</sub>

I get that organising an internationally available prize would be more complicated, but could something have been worked out given that half of the user base is outside the US?

Even if it was limited to the top 5 countries (by user count) that would raise the 'coverage' to approx 75%.

Please don't forget all us international users.  We wanna join the fun too!

Comment: Hey, don't forget us Canadians!  Most of us are close enough to the US to get to an REI.

Comment: David + @Ward - I feel your pain! But a semi-exclusive contest is better than no contest at all. And the next contest will likely be held outside the US -- in fact, we want to get one running Down Under. Thanks for your input, and stay tuned!

Comment: Hmm. I always thought we had more users in Australia/New Zealand than this. I guess our members Down Under are very active!

Comment: @David - If you have thoughts on how to organize a contest where the same retailer or manufacturer has stores - or dealers - in all countries, I'm sure Sam would love to hear your ideas.

Comment: @SamTheBrand - Don't get me wrong.  Serving 50% of your users is better than serving none of them.  Totally agree.  Just a friendly nudge to remind you that we (non-US) are still here ; )

Comment: @NeilFein - The first thing that comes to mind is deal direct with the manufacturer, who can then hook up the winner with their local distributor/retailer.  Most manufacturers have international distribution networks.   The other option is don't limit it to a single retailer.  Run it almost like a cash prize but only payable directly to your LBS.  The downside of this approach is that it removes any sponsorship/advertising type deals that could worked with the retailer/manufacturer.

Comment: @NeilFein - I know this is not news to you but posting it for completeness.  Some examples of manufacturers international disto networks: http://www.trekbikes.com/worldwide
http://www.cannondale.com/distributors-international
 http://chargebikes.com/distributors/
http://www.eddymerckx.be/dealers
http://www.pashley.co.uk/international-dealers.php
http://www.scott-sports.com/gb_en/dealers

Comment: @SamTheBrand No pain here: I meant that I'm close enough (and so are more Canadians) to the US that if I won I'd be down at REI in Seattle ASAP.

Comment: @David - Thanks!

Comment: @Ward - Didn't there used to be a few REIs in Canada, or am I imagining things? (There are certainly none now if you go to the REI site.)

Comment: We have MEC - Mountain Equipment Co-op  www.mec.ca

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, don't know if this should be an answer or a new meta question, but it seems to make more sense here...

Just to clarify:

- Does every question on the site that's at least +2 count as an entry, or is the contest only for questions asked during the contest period?
- I've posted links to a question of mine all over the place and have gotten it up to 100+ views.  That should include at least 25 different people from all over the place, but I don't have an "Announcer" badge yet.  I've seen another comment that it takes a few days for those badges to show up, but is there any way to tell if I'm going to get that badge?  Or do I just have to wait?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's meant to be questions that get asked or answers posted during the contest time period.

Comment: @Ward - It appears you haven't quite earned 25 unique views thru that link. Keep at it!